# How to programmatically detect residual files & folders left by other application in SD Card in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

How do I programmatically detect the residual files and folders created by another applications in SD Card. I don't know where to start from ? Is there is any android's API or do I need to implement my own logic. Please help in starting this.Thanks

Comment: What is a residual file?

Comment: By residual file, I meant all the files and folder created by an application on SD Card and when that app is uninstalled, those leftover files and folders, I want to detect them.

Comment: In a more simple way, when any application is uninstalled from my device, I want to check if the uninstalled application has created any file or folder in SD Card. If yes, then I want to detect those left overs. I simply dont know where to start from.

Comment: Looks impossible to me. How would you know where apps store data?

Comment: But applications like clean master and many more are doing the same na...